# Why do I get a vbscript compilation error

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

New to stackoverflow and hoping I can get some help. I'm getting this error:

> **TITLE: Package Validation Error**
>
> Package Validation Error
>
> ---
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Error at CSV_File_Reformat [ActiveX Script Task]: User script threw an 
>      exception: "Error Code: 0
>      Error Source= Microsoft VBScript compilation error
>      Error Description: Expected end of statement
>      Error on Line 12
>      ".
>
> Error at CSV_File_Reformat: There were errors during task validation.
>
> (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)

---

BUTTONS:

**OK**

This code works when running it in VBA, but when I try it as VBScript in an SSIS package it throws this error.

Here is the code:

```
Function Weekly_Upload_Reformat_IPS_File()

Dim xl_app
Dim wb
Dim lastRow


Set xl_app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("\\fs1-pdc-plpgh\Transportation - DW\IPS\TFS_FULL_DATA_WEEKLY_*")

For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
   If wb.Name Like "TFS_FULL_DATA_WEEKLY_*" Then wb.Activate
Next wb

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Rows("1:1").Select

Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "Detail"
Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = "Pro Number"
Range("C1").FormulaR1C1 = "Primary Bill of Lading"
Range("D1").FormulaR1C1 = "PO Number"
Range("E1").FormulaR1C1 = "Invoice Number"
Range("F1").FormulaR1C1 = "Date-Received at IPS"
Range("G1").FormulaR1C1 = "Date-Shipment"
Range("H1").FormulaR1C1 = "Date-Invoice"
Range("I1").FormulaR1C1 = "Date-Delivery Date"
Range("J1").FormulaR1C1 = "Delivery Time"
Range("K1").FormulaR1C1 = "Carrier-SCAC Code"
Range("L1").FormulaR1C1 = "Carrier-Name"
Range("M1").FormulaR1C1 = "Carrier-Major Mode"
Range("N1").FormulaR1C1 = "Carrier-Account Number"
Range("O1").FormulaR1C1 = "Received From"
Range("P1").FormulaR1C1 = "EDI/Paper (E/P)"
Range("Q1").FormulaR1C1 = "Invoice Type (Org/BD/Supp)"
Range("R1").FormulaR1C1 = "Accessorial-Description"
Range("S1").FormulaR1C1 = "Accessorial-Net"
Range("T1").FormulaR1C1 = "Shipper Name"
Range("U1").FormulaR1C1 = "Shipper Address"
Range("V1").FormulaR1C1 = "Shipper City"
Range("W1").FormulaR1C1 = "Shipper State"
Range("X1").FormulaR1C1 = "Shipper Country"
Range("Y1").FormulaR1C1 = "Shipper Zip"
Range("Z1").FormulaR1C1 = "Consignee Contact"
Range("AA1").FormulaR1C1 = "Consignee Name"
Range("AB1").FormulaR1C1 = "Consignee Address"
Range("AC1").FormulaR1C1 = "Consignee City"
Range("AD1").FormulaR1C1 = "Consignee State"
Range("AE1").FormulaR1C1 = "Consignee Country"
Range("AF1").FormulaR1C1 = "Consignee Zip"
Range("AG1").FormulaR1C1 = "Invoice Status (Pay/Rej/Hold)"
Range("AH1").FormulaR1C1 = "Currency"
Range("AI1").FormulaR1C1 = "Status/Week Ending Date"
Range("AJ1").FormulaR1C1 = "Check Number"
Range("AK1").FormulaR1C1 = "Process Loc (DataEntry/Audit)"
Range("AL1").FormulaR1C1 = "Payment Type (Payment/Credit/Debit)"
Range("AM1").FormulaR1C1 = "Terms"
Range("AN1").FormulaR1C1 = "Dim Factor"
Range("AO1").FormulaR1C1 = "Weight-Actual"
Range("AP1").FormulaR1C1 = "Weight-As Wgt"
Range("AQ1").FormulaR1C1 = "WGT Measure:pounds/kilos"
Range("AR1").FormulaR1C1 = "Pieces"
Range("AS1").FormulaR1C1 = "Number of Containers"
Range("AT1").FormulaR1C1 = "International Code"
Range("AU1").FormulaR1C1 = "Delivery Term (Door-Door/Airp-Airp/Etc)"
Range("AV1").FormulaR1C1 = "Service Level (Next Day/2nd Day/Etc)"
Range("AW1").FormulaR1C1 = "Client Mode"
Range("AX1").FormulaR1C1 = "Index Number"
Range("AY1").FormulaR1C1 = "Freight Class"

Range("B:E, AJ:AJ, AX:AX").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0"

Cells.Replace What:=",", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
    xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Cells.Replace What:="'", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
    xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Cells.Replace What:="""", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
    xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

Columns("W:W").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("W1").FormulaR1C1 = "Shipper City"
Range("W2").FormulaR1C1 = "=TRIM(RC[-1])"
lastRow = Range("V" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("W2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("W2:W" & lastRow)
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Columns("V:V").Delete

Columns("AD:AD").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("AD1").FormulaR1C1 = "Consignee City"
Range("AD2").FormulaR1C1 = "=TRIM(RC[-1])"
lastRow = Range("AC" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("AD2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AD2:AD" & lastRow)
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Columns("AC:AC").Delete

Columns("AZ:AZ").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("AZ1").FormulaR1C1 = "Freight Class"
Range("AZ2").FormulaR1C1 = "=TRIM(RC[-1])"
lastRow = Range("AY" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("AZ2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AZ2:AZ" & lastRow)
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Columns("AY:AY").Delete

ActiveSheet.Range("A:AY").AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:= _
    "0001-01-01"
Range("I2:I" & lastRow).Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Selection.ClearContents
ActiveSheet.Range("A:AY").AutoFilter Field:=9

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="\\fs1-pdc-plpgh\Transportation - DW\IPS\Staging\IPS Upload.csv", _
    FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I don't understand how to use the application object explicitly in my code. What line do I need to change and what do I need to change it to?

Comment: Things like `xlPart`, `xlByRows` and all other enums need to be defined in VBScript. You can get the underlying value by using `?xlPart` in the immediate window in Excel.

Comment: @NRJ87103 it's not change one thing, there are multiple problems because you are expecting to take a VBA macro and copy and paste it directly into a SSIS Script Task and expect it to work. VBScript has no idea what `Application` is you have to give it context from this code I'd say `xl_app` is the equivalent to the `Application` object but don't quote me on that.

Comment: @Lankymart got it, that makes sense. Thank you for the responses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`VBScript` is not interchangeable with `VBA`. `VBScript` is a subset of `VBA`, so you can't simply copy paste an excel macro to a `.vbs` file and run it.

Otherwise your error `"Error Description: Expected end of statement"` means that you are missing quotes on a string or you're missing a one part of an equation (for example if you write `my_var =` without anything on the other side of the `=`)

Also I think that there is no `Like` keyword in `VBScript`, use this instead `Left(wb.Name, Len("TFS_FULL_DATA_WEEKLY_")) = "TFS_FULL_DATA_WEEKLY_"`

> I recommend that you put the VBA code in the excel file and then use VBScript to open the file and trigger the macro

Comment: Actually, it's because `If wb.Name Like "TFS_FULL_DATA_WEEKLY_*" Then wb.Activate` isn't valid syntax, VBScript wouldn't be expecting `Like` so the `If` statement isn't complete, hence `Expected end of statement`.

Comment: @reportgunner I went with your recommendation to leave the VBA code in the excel file and trigger it using VBScript. This ended up being the simplest solution rather than trying to rework the code for VBScript.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Having to rewrite from VBA to VBScript is an uphill battle.